# SAS - Dynamically adding text to an email via a %macro

Tags: email, macros, sas, sas-macro

I'm attempting to dynamically display text within an email by using a %macro in the place of the dynamic text. This *was* working, but after adding a few additional lines of text to my email, it stopped working. So, I'm unsure of what is causing the actual issue. Reverting back to where I was when it was working no longer works.

My macro I'm calling:

```
%macro PrintStuff(arrayOfThings);
    %local i next_element;
    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&arrayOfThings));
        %let next_element = %scan(&arrayOfThings, &i);
        %DO;
            %PUT "&next_element info is as follows:";
            %PUT "some text here";
            %PUT "some text there";
            %PUT "text all over!!!";
            %PUT "Do you even text?";
        %END;
    %end;
%mend PrintStuff;
```

email code:

```
DATA _null_;
    File mailFile;
    PUT "This is email text. This shows up fine in the email";
    %PrintStuff(&someArray);
    PUT "This closes the email, and this shows up fine in the email when it is received!"
RUN;
```

I've tried a few different things here. I've tried ONLY having %PrintStuff(&myArrayOrList) in the email. I've tried it with and without a closing **;** semicolon. I'm not sure where this went wrong.

The log appears this way after the code has run successfully:

```
50         DATA _null_;
51          File outmail;
52          PUT "This is email text. This shows up fine in the email";
53         
54          %PrintStuff(&someArray)
"ResolvedElementName info is as follows:"
"some text here"
"some text there"
"some text all over!!!"
"Do you even text?"
55         
56          PUT "This closes the email, and this shows up fine in the email when it is received!";
57         RUN;
```

It worked, and now it doesn't, and I'm not sure how it could have worked before now. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the data step, `put` writes into `outmail`. `%PUT` on the other hand writes into log. I can't test it, but try to replace `%put` in the macro by`put`.

Comment: @Petr Thank you so much. That did the trick! If you want to go ahead and write that as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Put` in data step writes into output table/file (i.e. outmail in your example), `%put` in your macro writes into log. Try replacing `%put` in the macro by `put` - it will add those 5 lines to your data step.